Подчеркивание ошибок VSCode C++
Создал простой проект HelloWorld с системой сборки CMake.
Он собирается и компилируется, запускается. НО, почему VSCode подчеркивает включение iostream как ошибку? Логично что он (я так понимаю IntelliSense) почему то библиотеки не видит.
Я указывал в cpp_properties.json путь до .h файлов компилятора, очищал базу Intelli Sense (Cntrl+Shift+P -> Reset IntelliSense), но ничего не помогает.


Покажите c_cpp_properties.json.

Попробуйте пересоздать кэш cmake F1 -> CMake delete cache and reconfigure. Также посмотрите точно ли выбран нужный вам набор компилятора F1 -> CMake select a kit. Добавьте в вопрос CMakeLists.txt. Также можете настроить intelisense с помощью ui F1 -> C/C++ edit configurations (UI)

Проблема решена. Почему то был выбран компилятор (msvc), а intelli sense был настроен под GCC
